# How to print acronym with math environment bold in the index?

Tags: indexing, bold, acronyms

I have loaded the acronym package and added an mathenvironment into the options of \acronym. But now the acronym will not be printed bold into the listing of acronyms. How can I print it bold (only in the index not in the body.)?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[footnote, printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}
    \section{index}
    \begin{acronym}[Abkürzungen]
        \acro{PC}{personal computer}
        \acro{RAM}{Random Access Memmory}
        \acro{HDD}{hard disk drive}
        \acro{pi}[$\pi$]{pi}        
    \end{acronym}

\section{body}
Some hardware components of a \ac{PC} are the \ac{HDD} and the \ac{RAM}.
A thing that is not a component of a \ac{PC} is \ac{pi}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get bold math in the labels you can add `\boldmath` to the `\aclabelfont`.
Just add

```
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\boldmath\acsfont{#1}}}
```

in your preamble.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the package 'textgreek', and then use \textpi instead of $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I am searching for. The $\pi$ was only an example. For any math environment.